# How to create a Json Object with empty strings and send it as a Web Service Response

Tags: java, json, cxf, jax-rs

I was querying and getting data from database using Spring jdbctemplate rowmapper. Once I get the data I was mapping it to a Java object and converting it to a json object.

My json object contains contains a object with 2 fields

```
code 
status
```

When I was getting the data from database I was passing 200 and success data to the above 2 fields and passing the json object as web service response.

My actual question is even if I didn't get any data, I need to pass the json object as web service response but with code as "404" amd message field as "no data" and other fields are to be empty strings ("") , similarly if any exception occurred, need to send json object with empty strings but with 503 code.

How can I do that?

My method code snippet:

```
  userdtls= userDaoimpl.getUserdetails(userId);             
        if (userdtls== null) {
            ResponseBuilder builder =       Response.ok(convertToJson(userdtls),MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("No such user " + userdtls+);
            throw new WebApplicationException(builder .build());
        }
```

convertToJson.java

```
      public String convertToJson(UserData userdtls) {

        StatusData status = new StatusData ();
        status.setCode("200");
        status.setMessage("Success");

                    userdtls.setStatus(status);
                    PersonalData personal = new PersonalData();
                    personal.setdob("june11");
                      personal.setage("28");

                     userdtls.setPersonal(personal);

                 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
      return gson.toJson(userdtls));
```

Comment: how about `status.setCode("404"); status.setMessage("no data");`

Comment: yeah i know that...! but my question how to create the various json objects based on the exception raised- i want different 200 with data ,404 code with empty data ,503 code with empty data.where to call and when to call it and for what exceptions